# Which if statement would execute faster?

Tags: performance, algorithm, theory

Let's say the we have an object and that we need to validate the following things -

- Object->text length is greater than 0
- Object->dummy is not null
- Objecct->dummy2 exists in another object

We have two possibilities for a if statement:

```
if(greaterThan(Object->text, 0) && 
   exists(Objet->dummy) && 
   inObject(Object->dummy2, Objet2))
```

Second if:

```
if(!greaterThan(Object->text, 0) || 
       !exists(Objet->dummy) || 
       !inObject(Object->dummy2, Objet2)) {
  NOP  
 } else {
   //Do something;
}
```

Which one would be faster? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you care? Do you notice a performance hit exactly there? I truly doubt. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"... Just write what is easiest to read.

Comment: generalu first one as you have less operations worst case of first one is 2 AND while worst case of second one is 2 OR and 3 NEGATION

Comment: Why do you care why he cares? By just repeating the tired "premature optimization..." quote you are are implicitly assuming that the OP is actually optimizing this prematurely and even that he's optimizing it all. Sometimes you just want to know _why_ even if there is no practical benefit. Indeed, the question is tagged with "Theory"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, those two forms are equivalent and a decent compiler would likely compile them to the same final assembly. You should check on your specific compiler, of course. You can take a look at the assembly output of a few compilers here for your problem:

http://goo.gl/FeSmEa

For example, the gcc 4.9 output:

```
void function1() {
  if (greaterThan() &&  exists() && inObject()) {
    result = 42;
  }
}
```

gives:

```
function1():
    sub rsp, 8
    call    greaterThan()
    test    eax, eax
    jne .L13
.L1:
    add rsp, 8
    ret
.L13:
    call    exists()
    test    eax, eax
    je  .L1
    call    inObject()
    test    eax, eax
    je  .L1
    mov DWORD PTR result[rip], 42
    jmp .L1
```

while, the other variant:

```
void function2() {
  if (!greaterThan() ||  !exists() || !inObject()) {
    // NOP
  } else {
    result = 42;
  }
}
```

leads to identical assembly:

```
function2():
    sub rsp, 8
    call    greaterThan()
    test    eax, eax
    jne .L28
.L14:
    add rsp, 8
    ret
.L28:
    call    exists()
    test    eax, eax
    je  .L14
    call    inObject()
    test    eax, eax
    je  .L14
    mov DWORD PTR result[rip], 42
    jmp .L14
```

In all cases the compilers produced identical assembly for both options (I simplified it slightly by removing some arguments, but that should be immaterial).

Comment: Yes, I fully expect all sensible compilers to compile them identically.

Comment: oh wow, that's interesting. I was asking because I've wanted to prevent the if from calling other functions, thanks

Comment: You don't need to look at the assembly to determine that - the language defines shot-circuit boolean operators, and so by definition you will not call functions when the value of the boolean expression is already set. As far as that behavior goes, your two expressions are equivalent.

What matters in that case is the order you put your expressions in. You want the one that is more likely to "short circuit" the rest of the expression first. For example, for `A && B` you want to put whichever of `A` or `B` is most likely to be false, first.